# Different ways of using router links?

Tags: angular2-routing

Im still learning Angular and I come across an example of using links for routes that I had not seen.  Going through the docs on Angular.io, Im using to seeing and using this format:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

```
template: `
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 `
```

Then, I was reading an article here:
http://blog.ng-book.com/basic-routing-in-angular-2/

```
  <a>Navigation:</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a [router-link]="['home']">Home</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['login']">Login</a></li>
    <li><a [router-link]="['dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
  </ul>
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First example you provided, the data is passed as a raw value, therefore it can be set as a static value

Second example, it can be bound to a variable from the component, not necessarily, it's just a different way which offers more flexibility of what you can do with the router.

They would both deliver you the same result if you simply type in a raw value, but if you need a value from the component, for example, retrieve a value from the database, the second one would be more ideal.